# How to route to my posts internally with nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

Trying to pass internal links in my template, but it does not direct to the links.

```
<nuxt-link
              to="blog.url"
              >{{ blog.title }} by {{ blog.author }}</nuxt-link
            >
```

And in my data I have this (where blog.title and blog.author correctly work)

```
data() {
    return {
      blog: [
        { url: '/blog1', title: 'my first title', author: 'Brad' },
        { url: '/blog2', title: 'my second title', author: 'James' },
        { url: '/blog3', title: 'my third title', author: 'Tom' }
]
}
}
```

The output from the nuxt-link is simply "blog.url" and does not route anywhere. How to make it route to my internal links specified per blog1, blog2, blog3?

Answer (score 1):

You want `:to`, not `to`. Without the colon, you’re pointing to the string “blog.url”, not your data.